# Bootstrap - Right Aligned Menu in Navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am writing an app that uses Boostrap 3.3. It also uses open source [material design framework](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html). My app has a table that lists users. Each row in the table has a picture, a person name, an email address, and an action menu. Here is my current code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email address</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><div><i class="material-icons">person</i></div></td>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
      <td>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="material-icons">more_vert</i><div class="ripple-container"></div></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The action menu opens left-aligned against the menu icon. However, I'm trying to make it right-aligned so that the content opens to the left. The behavior of the right "Dropdown" link in the Navbar section of the [example](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html) is what I'm trying to reproduce. Yet, I'm not having any luck. I added a `float:right` on the `ul` without any luck. What am I missing?

Comment: so you want action, another action right align..right?

Comment: if yes then in .dropdown-menu>li>a use text-align:right

Comment: Replace `<ul class="dropdown-menu">` with `<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">`

Comment: @C0dekid.php, sorry but i made that comment before your edit in which div tag inside div without closing so..leave that comment :)

Comment: Haha it's ok! Does that work anyways? @Leothelion

Comment: well i m not op...already mentioned that line..waiting for op's reaction.

Comment: @C0dekid.php thanks. That was the problem. I overlooked the `dropdown-menu-right` class in the docs.

Comment: You're welcome! I have posted this as an answer, you can accept it if you want to:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Bootstrap` there is a class called `dropdown-menu-right`. If you add this to your dropdown menu, the menu will appears on the right side instead off on the left (by default).

Simply replace this:

`<li class="dropdown-menu">`

With:

`<li class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">`

See reference: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

> Note: the `.pull-right` is now deprecated to dropdown menus in bootstrap V3.1.0.